# Why does deleting a global variable named __builtins__ prevent only the REPL from accessing builtins?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, built-in, cpython

I have a python script with the following contents:

```
# foo.py

__builtins__ = 3
del __builtins__

print(int)  # <- this still works
```

Curiously, executing this script with the `-i` flag prevents *only* the REPL from accessing builtins:

```
aran-fey@starlight ~> python3 -i foo.py 
<class 'int'>
>>> print(int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```

How come the script can access builtins, but the REPL can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython doesn't look up `__builtins__` every time it needs to do a built-in variable lookup. Each frame object has an [`f_builtins`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Include/frameobject.h#L21) member holding its built-in variable dict, and built-in variable lookup goes through there.

`f_builtins` is set on frame object creation. If a new frame has *no parent frame* (`f_back`), or a *different global variable dict* from its parent frame, then frame object initialization looks up `__builtins__` to set `f_builtins`. (If the new frame shares a global dict with its parent frame, then it inherits its parent's `f_builtins`.) This is the only way `__builtins__` is involved in built-in variable lookup. You can see the code that handles this in [`_PyFrame_New_NoTrack`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/frameobject.c#L667).

When you delete `__builtins__` inside a script, that doesn't affect `f_builtins`. The rest of the code executing in the script's stack frame still sees builtins. Once the script completes and `-i` drops you into interactive mode, every interactive command gets a new stack frame (with no parent), and the `__builtins__` lookup is repeated. This is when the deleted `__builtins__` finally matter.

Answer (score 3):

The execution context is different. Within the REPL we are working line-by-line (**R**ead, **E**val, **P**rint, **L**oop), which allows an opportunity for global execution scope to change in between each step. But the runtime executing a module is to load the modules code, and then exec it within a scope.

In CPython, the builtins namespace associated with the execution of a code block is found by looking up the name `__builtins__` in the global namespace; this should be bound to a dictionary or a module (in the latter case the module's dictionary is used). When in the `__main__` module, `__builtins__` is the built-in module `builtins`, otherwise `__builtins__` is bound to the dictionary of the `builtins` module itself. In both contexts of your question, we are in the `__main__` module.

What's important is that CPython only looks up the builtins **once**, right before it begins executing your code. In the REPL, this happens every time a new statement is executed. But when executing a python script, the entire content of the script is one single unit. That is why deleting the builtins in the middle of the script has no effect.

To more closely replicate that context inside a REPL, you would not enter the code of the module line by line, but instead use a compound statement:

```
>>> if 1:
...     del __builtins__
...     print(123)
... 
123
>>> print(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```

Naturally, you're probably now wondering how to remove builtins from within a script. The answer should be obvious: you can't do it by rebinding a name, but you can do it by mutation:

```
# foo2.py
__builtins__.__dict__.clear()
print(int)  # <- NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```

As a final note, the fact that `__builtins__` name is bound at all is [implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#builtins-and-restricted-execution) of CPython and that is explicitly documented:

> Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it is strictly an implementation detail.

Don't rely on `__builtins__` for anything serious, if you need access to that scope the correct way is to `import builtins` and go from there.