# How are the contents of the builtins module available in the global namespace without import in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using Python for a good period of time. I have never found out how built-in functions work. In different words, how are they included without having any module imported to use them? What if I want to add to them (locally)?

This may seem naive. But, I haven't really found any answer that explains comprehensively how do we have built-in functions, global variables, etc., available to us when developing a script.

In a nutshell, where do we include the [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module?

I have encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965090/how-to-add-builtin-functions). But it gives a partial answer to my question.

Comment: They are built directly into the interpreter

Comment: You mean, they're compiled into the interpreter executable?

Comment: Yes, they are part of the interpreter itself, not separated out into their own modules

Comment: You don't want to add to them (locally), except by defining non-built in functions. The last thing you want for readable code is functions that aren't in the standard globals but randomly appear anyway.

Comment: @UnholySheep they are in the `builtins` module though.

Comment: @gilch: And there is [some (limited) precedent for dynamically adding stuff to the built-in namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module).

Comment: @ShadowRanger besides the standard library, I know that ipython and xonsh mess with builtins.

Comment: For example the `gettext` package is able to "install" new functions (e.g. `_()`) into that builtins namespace. See "class based API" in the packages docu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The not-implementation-details part of the answer is that the `builtins` module, or `__builtin__` in Python 2, provides access to the built-ins namespace. If you want to modify the built-ins (you usually shouldn't), setting attributes on `builtins` is how you'd go about it.

The implementation details part of the answer is that Python keeps track of built-ins in multiple ways. For example, each frame object keeps track of the built-in namespace it's using, which may be different from other frames' built-in namespaces. You can access this through a frame's `f_builtins` attribute. When a [`LOAD_GLOBAL`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Python/ceval.c#L2108) instruction fails to find a name in the frame's globals, it [looks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/dictobject.c#L1429) in the frame's builtins. There's also a `__builtins__` global variable in most global namespaces, but it's not directly used for built-in variable lookup; instead, it's used to initialize `f_builtins` in [certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221983/why-does-deleting-a-global-variable-named-builtins-prevent-only-the-repl-fro/52318537#52318537) during frame object creation. There's also a `builtins` reference in the global `PyInterpreterState`, which is [used as default builtins](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Python/ceval.c#L4412) if there's no current frame object.

Comment: The docs for the `exec` function also mention that you can customize which `__builtins__` it uses by specifying it in the globals dict argument.

Comment: @gilch: That's not *quite* what they say, but under usual circumstances, setting `__builtins__` in the global dict passed to `exec` will control the builtins used for the executed code, through the usual initialize-`f_builtins`-from-`__builtins__` handling. There is a weird exception [if you try to set `__builtins__` in the current globals and then pass those globals to `exec`](https://ideone.com/yl9fvN), since that hits the other code path for initializing `f_builtins`.